# C# typesafe cloning with generics

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to create a generic container object (done; no problem) which can be deep cloned. That means it has to deep clone its contained objects, and it's this that is causing me problems. Here's some code:

```
    public abstract class VehiclePart {
        public abstract T cloneTypesafe<T>()
                        where T : VehiclePart, new() // L1
    }


    public class Gearstick : VehiclePart { // L2

        public Gearstick() { }

        public override T cloneTypesafe<T>() {
            var res2 = new Gearstick();
            return res2; // L3
            return (T)res2; // L4
        }
    }
```

It rejects this (comment L3) saying “Cannot implicitly convert type 'LDB.Program.Gearstick' to 'T'”, but that makes no sense because T is explicitly derived from VehiclePart (Line L1), and Gearstick is explicitly derived from VehiclePart (line L2), so the conversion should be entirely legal.

Even if I had an explicit cast (line L4) it's not happy ("Cannot convert type 'LDB.Program.Gearstick' to 'T'"), so what's the problem and how do I fix this?  (I don’t want to use reflection, which seems to be a common suggestion in answers to similar questions. I have read several comments saying not to use ICloneable).

Comment: `T` may be derived from `VehiclePart`, but not every `VehiclePart` also derives from `Gearstick` - hence you cannot cast to every possible `T`

Comment: As a possible alternative, in C# 9, covariant return types allow `VehiclePart cloneTypeSafe()` to be overridden as `Gearstick cloneTypeSafe()` without the use of generics.

Comment: @UnholySheep: if I add a constraint "public class Gearstick<T> : VehiclePart where T : VehiclePart, new() {" then the error goes, but I don't understand why. The problem is I'm basically out of my depth here. I think I just need to accept I'm not up to this yet and work around it.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: yep, I'm vaguely aware of this from a prior question but I don't want to upgrade yet. Thanks though.

Comment: Having spent a lot of time trying to do something similar before giving up, I would say that unfortunately this is just not really something the C# type system is currently able to achieve. Your best bet is to just have `public abstract VehiclePart Clone()` and let the caller cast it if they need to, or make it not abstract and each derived type return its own type. (Although it depends on what you're actually doing with it if this is a reasonable solution.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> so what's the problem

The signature of your method allows me to call your code as follows:

```
CarWindow myCarWindow = myGearstick.cloneTypesafe<CarWindow>();
```

This is a valid call, since `CarWindow` is a subtype of `VehiclePart`. Still, it should be obvious that this call is nonsensical.

---

> and how do I fix this?

With C# 9.0 or newer, you can use covariant return types, see [Guru Stron's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65668149/87698).

If you are stuck with earlier versions, see [Jamiec's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65667629/87698) for a possible solution. Alternatively, you could extract the method into your own `IDeepCloneable<T>` interface for separation of concerns:

```
public interface IDeepCloneable<T>
{
    T CloneTypesafe();
}

public class Gearstick : VehiclePart, IDeepCloneable<Gearstick>
{
    public Gearstick CloneTypesafe() { ... }
}
```

Note that, as Jamiec pointed out in the comments, the type system won't stop you from making nonsensical declarations such as `public class Gearstick : VehiclePart, IDeepClonable<Windscreen>`.

Comment: I think I would personally prefer your separate interface solution. It suffers the same problem though of allowing `public class Gearstick : VehiclePart, IDeepClonable<Windscreen>`

Comment: "Unfortunately C# does not support covariant return types" -> see c#9.0

Answer (score 3):

With C# 9 you can remove the need of generics here and use [covariant return types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/covariant-returns):

```
public abstract class VehiclePart
{
    public abstract VehiclePart cloneTypesafe();
}    

public class Gearstick : VehiclePart {

    public Gearstick() { }

    public override Gearstick cloneTypesafe()
    {
        return new Gearstick(); // your actual implementation
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a misuse of generics. If you use generics, you are saying that the caller of the method can pass in whatever type they want (with some constraints), and your method will still work. This is clearly not the case here. Your `cloneTypesafe` method in `Gearstick` will *only* work if `T` is `Gearstick`. If `T` is, e.g. `Engine`, or `Wheel`, then the cast will fail.

`cloneTypesafe` should really return "the type of the class that it is in", but we have no way of saying that in C#. You can do this as a work around though:

```
public abstract class VehiclePart<T> 
    where T : VehiclePart<T>, new(){ // implementers are supposed to replace T with their class
    public abstract T cloneTypesafe();
}

// you are not "forced" to say ": VehiclePart<Gearstick>", hence why this is only a workaround
public class Gearstick : VehiclePart<Gearstick> {
    public override Gearstick cloneTypesafe() {
        var res2 = new Gearstick();
        // copy some properties...
        return res2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For this to work as (I think) you expected, you should have the generic definition on the abstract class itself

```
public abstract class VehiclePart<T> where T: new() {
    public abstract T cloneTypesafe();
}

public class Gearstick : VehiclePart<Gearstick> { // L2

    public Gearstick() { }

    public override Gearstick cloneTypesafe() {
        var res2 = new Gearstick();
        return res2; 
    }
}
```

Comment: But it is worth remembering I can still write `public class Gearstick : VehiclePart<Wheel>` and the compiler is fine with that

Comment: Might be worth pointing out the drawback here - nothing forces the `T` to be the derived type - `public class SteeringWheel : VehiclePart<Gearstick> {}` will also be accepted by the type system.

Comment: ^^ What those guys said!

Comment: Yeah, I have managed to clone a wheel from a gearstick myself... That's ok I think. The deeper problem is I just haven't sufficient experience with generics beyond the basics. Any suggestions on advance reading?